# FatalThrowableError with Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, ipb

I'm implementing IPB4 in my Laravel project, and for this I put in the boot (AppServiceProvider) code to see if the user is logged in the forum.

```
   $url_base = \IPS\Settings::i()->base_url;
   \IPS\Session\Front::i(); 
   $avatar = $url_base."uploads/".\IPS\Member::loggedIn()->pp_main_photo;
   $member = \IPS\Member::loggedIn()->member_id;
   $key = \IPS\Session::i()->csrfKey;
```

Everything works correctly, only when I use composer, I always get this error:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\lv>php artisan serve
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Class 'IPS\Settings' not found
```

When i do every anything... php artisan serve, composer update, install package... In order to continue, I have to comment on the code... Because otherwise, I get the error. If commenting on the code entered in boot (AppServiceProvider) composer works correctly, I do something wrong..

Comment: `IPS\Settings` has likely not been bound in the app container at that point.

Comment: You could try to use that at the top of your file (namespacing), something like `use IPS\Settings`

Comment: I put the use IPS\Settings;use IPS\Member; but it still gives me a composer error ... while instead the local code works correctly... The forum is in: /lv/forum and laravel in /lv

Answer (score 0):

I solved by inserting in composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
      "files": [
        "forum/init.php"
    ],
```